# Packet capture on ESXi host

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, wireshark, tcpdump

I have an issue I am trying to track down and I believe the problem is with physical networking hardware. I have read the [VMWare](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc%2FGUID-30003897-2101-459C-81FA-FCB42313237E.html) documentation on the pktcap-uw command and I know I can use it to dump the traffic to a file which can then be viewed with Wireshark, but the pcaps I am getting are a little weird.

Looking at the documentation, I want to see traffic only between two IP addresses (IP A and IP B) on port 80 and I can use the --ip switch, but if I have --ip A --ip B, is that a boolean AND or a boolean OR.

tcpdump allows you to specify OR or AND and use parenthesis to do a full boolean expression. For pktcap-uw there is also --dstip and --srcip, but if you use the tcpdump equivelant, you would normally get only half the conversation.

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Just do a port mirror on the switch ? And use wireshark after

Comment: That equipment is outside of my perview. Network team tracked it down to  an IP conflict though.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested with pktcap-uw.

> if I have --ip A --ip B, is that a boolean AND or a boolean OR.

When you specify --ip two times, only the last specified option is used.

If you specify different types of options, eg. --ip and --tcpport, they are ANDed.

There are some VProbe options to pktcap-uw.  My best guess for going forward would be that you may be able to manually compile a VProbe script that filters the traffic that you want and feed it to pktcap-uw.

Found a git repository with a VProbe toolkit here:
https://github.com/vmware/vprobe-toolkit/